# AngularJS: NgShow Evaluate Object Properties in Collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I have a scope variable with this structure:

```
var $scope.messages = [ 
  {
    id: '1',
    body: 'Foo',
    status: 'read'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    body: 'Bar',
    status: 'read'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    body: 'Hello',
    status: 'unread'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    body: 'World',
    status: 'unread'
  },
]
```

At the HTML layout, I have ng-show directive like this:

```
<div class="loaderContainer" ng-show="isAnyNewMessage() > 0">
   You have unread message(s)
</div>

function isAnyNewMessage(){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.messages.length; i++){
    if($scope.messages[i].status == 'unread'){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

I want to show `.loaderContainer` if there's any message with `status: unread`. 
How to achieve a proper ng-show condition?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdcbqdcg/1/

---

Sorry folks, I've made a mistake.

The evaluation function (`isAnyNewMessage`) should be a member of `$scope` variable like this:

```
$scope.isAnyNewMessage = function() {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.messages.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.messages[i].status == 'unread') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
};
```

Comment: From those sample I have 2 unread message, so the `.loaderContainer `should be shown up

Comment: how do you get your messages? from an ajax call?

Comment: Technically no, but actually it was simmilar to ajax. Let's say it was from ajax

Comment: Do you get any errors? The code looks fine ...

Comment: I've update with jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $scope.isAnyNewMessage=function()  {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.messages.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.messages[i].status == 'unread') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
 }
```

Comment: define your function in this way..!!

Comment: oh ! i didnt chked your updated code ..!! so u already resolved that great..!!

Answer (score -1):

If you want a surely working answer, you have to provide a JSFiddle or your whole Controller. But, from your code:

The ng-show is a `true` or `false` variable. So you can call your function inside ng-show, but get sure you return true or false inside `isAnyNewMessage`.

For example:

```
function isAnyNewMessage(){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.messages.length; i++){
    if($scope.messages[i].status == 'unread'){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count > 0;
}

<div class="loaderContainer" ng-show="isAnyNewMessage()">
   You have unread message(s)
</div>
```

[See the docs for ngShow.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: this is pretty much what he's already doing, moving the >0 inside the function itself doesn't make a difference.